# Trigger not inserting records into table

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a trigger but it's not inserting the records into target table.

```
create or replace trigger ins_det_trig1
after insert on Table_a
declare
pragma    autonomous_transaction;
---
begin
insert into inf_det
select 
a.loc_id,
a.genre_id,
to_char(a.emp_date,'yyyy-mm-dd'),
a.san_seq
from Table_b a ,
Table_a b
where 
b.emp_date=a.emp_date
and   b.genre_id=a.genre_id
and   b.san_seq=a.san_seq;

commit;
exception
when others
Rollback;
end;
```

pls help me on this

Comment: Maybe start by removing the exception handler. Then you may see that your trigger is not inserting records because it raises an exception.

Comment: You probably get `table is mutating trigger/function may not see it` , don't you?

Comment: Unrelated comment to the answers below: are you sure you need ```pragma           autonomous_transaction;``` ? That can lead to unexpected results. If an insert happens on this table and then it is rolled back (for example because an error happens at a later point in the transaction), the trigger will do the insert and the data in inf_det will be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the trigger is invalid, so it won't do anything. You are using a variable named `v_err` that you don't declare.

Then, you are swallowing all exceptions. If something goes wrong, you fill that variable with the error code and then silently end the trigger. Thus you'll never get informed when the trigger fails.

But the main problem is that you are not using the trigger as you should use triggers in Oracle. The trigger is an **after row trigger** (`AFTER INSERT ... FOR EACH ROW`) and hence fires once per row on inserts of table_a rows. The values that got inserted in a new row can be accessed with `:new`, e.g. `:new.business_date`.

You, however, ignore these values and select from the table instead. But at the moment of your select the table is mutating. Let's say we write an insert statement that inserts two rows. The trigger fires two times. It is left to chance which row gets inserted first. Oracle sees this and when you are inside the trigger and try to select, it tells us that the content of the table is not deterministic, as the other row may already be in the table or not. We get a mutating table exception.

Having said this: It seems you want an **after statement trigger**. A trigger that fires after the insert of the rows is complete. For this to happen remove the `FOR EACH ROW` clause and the related `REFERENCING` clause, too.

```
create or replace trigger ins_det_trig1
after insert on Table_a
declare
  ...
begin
  ...
end;
```

Comment: As mentioned: It seems you don't want a row trigger at all. If you use an after satement trigger instead, there is no row, hence no :new.

Comment: As I said: Just remove the two clauses from your code. (And better remove the  exception block, too.) Your insert statement remains where it is, right after `BEGIN`.

Comment: So you removed the two clauses, removed the exception block, compiled the trigger, insert something into table_a, but you don't get an exception? Just nothing inserted into table inf_det? Does the select statement return rows when you run it standalone?